# pull-right not right aligning my buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to align all three buttons to the right. I am using pull-right to bring this effect, but it's not even budging this buttons a pixel. What is wrong in this code?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="goNext('/login')">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Note:** I don't want to use any javascript or jquery code to bring this effect

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this - this creates a single large column spanning the entire available width of the row and the pull-right moves all buttons to the right, this will move Reset to the extreme right

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="goNext('/login')">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This retains the order - the difference is that now we use a text-right on the wrapper cell to move everything to the righ

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="goNext('/login')">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you want blocks (that stretch 2 columns), you have to use column offsets instead of a float or an align to move the buttons to the right

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ng-click="goNext('/login')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But could you please elaborate your solution. It will be helpful to me in future.

Comment: @RishabhSharma - sure, which one are you using?